# MedeA VASP: Determination of carrier concentration

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, ab-initio-calculations

My question is, how do I calculate the carrier concentration from a DFT study? I am using MedeA VASP for the DFT simulation.

Comment: +1 and welcome to the site! Thanks you for contributing your question here, and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!! I haven't used MedeA-VASP before, but you might find this thread helpful: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1549/5

Comment: Also not a VASP user, but there was a brief thread about this on the VASP forum: https://www.vasp.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17609&p=18715

Comment: Can pl suggest method to calculate Carrier concentration from Density of state.... thank you in advance